# spring mvc and jdbc

Tags: spring, jdbc

I am beginning with spring and I am working on the web mvc. When not in MVC, as pointed in some tutorial, I would specify the data source in beans.xml and call this file with ApplicationContext object, and creating an object by passing the data source. And that worked for me. and when I came back to MVC, I created the data source in my name-servlet.xml file by using

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

and I have a superclass used for my service classes for data access, only with method setDataSource. and here is my sample.

```
@Resource(name="dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
    this.dataSource=dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

but I am still getting a null pointer exception when working with the dataSource. please what am i missing?

Comment: Do you have <context:annotation-driven/> in your XML?
And why don't you separate controllers and other beans XMLs?

Comment: I have <mvc:annotation-driven/>, which i still don't know the difference.